# SDL not responding after running for a few seconds on linux

Tags: c++, linux, sdl, sdl-2

I was following the SDL Game development book and I cant even get the first file to work right. Upon the application starting it renders the window and then after a few seconds Linux says the game is not responding and ask me to force quit. This repeats every few seconds if I click wait. One thing I have noticed is that SDL_PollEvent never returns true.I am not sure why things are not working. Here is my code.

Main.cpp

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include "Game.h"

// our Game object
Game* g_game = 0;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    g_game = new Game();
    g_game->init("Chapter 1", 100, 100, 640, 480, 0);
    while(g_game->running()) {
        g_game->handleEvents();
        //g_game->update();
        g_game->render();
    }
    g_game->clean();
    return 0;
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef __Game__
#define __Game__
#if !WINDOWS
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#else
#include <SDL.h>
#endif

class Game {
public:
    Game() {}
    ~Game() {}
// simply set the running variable to true
    bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int
        height, bool fullscreen);
    void render();
    void update();
    void handleEvents();
    void clean();
// a function to access the private running variable
    bool running() {
        return m_bRunning;
    }
private:

    SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;

    bool m_bRunning;
};

#endif /* defined(__Game__) */
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

bool Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width,
                int height, bool fullscreen) {
// attempt to initialize SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL init success\n";
// init the window
        int flags = 0;
        if(fullscreen) {
            flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos,
                                     width, height, flags);
        if(m_pWindow != 0) { // window init success
            std::cout << "window creation success\n";
            m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, 0);
            if(m_pRenderer != 0) { // renderer init success
                std::cout << "renderer creation success\n";
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_pRenderer,
                                       255,0,255,255);
            } else {
                std::cout << "renderer init fail\n";
                return false; // renderer init fail
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "window init fail\n";
            return false; // window init fail
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "SDL init fail\n";
        return false; // SDL init fail
    }
    std::cout << "init success\n";
    m_bRunning = true; // everything inited successfully, start the main loop
    return true;
}

void Game::render() {
    SDL_RenderClear(m_pRenderer); // clear the renderer to the draw color
    SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer); // draw to the screen
}

void Game::clean() {
    std::cout << "cleaning game\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::handleEvents() {
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        std::cout << "Checking Events";
        switch(event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            std::cout << "Quiting";
            m_bRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

so I made a minamal version of the code and now i get a new error. The error says "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)". Based on running it to a specific line in debug the error seems to appear at the line that says "SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);" I am not sure what the error is though

Here is the minial code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(win == NULL) {
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if(ren == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    std::string imagePath = "cb.bmp";
    SDL_Surface *bmp = SDL_LoadBMP(imagePath.c_str());
    if(bmp == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        std::cout << "SDL_LoadBMP Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);
    if(tex == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);
    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;
    while(!quit) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            //If user closes the window
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
            //If user presses any key
            if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                quit = true;
            }
            //If user clicks the mouse
            if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(ren);
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `handleEvent` can you add some debug info in default ?

Comment: @Thomas I change it to this: std::cout << "Still Running\n"; to default it never give any output even if I pressed keys or clicked. If I put debug in before the while loop, it is called outputted continually btw.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas cause the code looks fine to me

Comment: This a lot of code. Add a minimal example please.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled and run your minimal code successfully under Linux with SDL 2.0.4. I used a simple image as "cb.bmp".

Try the following :

1. compile like this : g++ -Wall -ggdb $(sdl2-config --cflags) -o program main.cpp -lSDL2
2. gdb ./program,  then type 'run'
3. when it crashes, type 'bt' (for backtrace)
4. copy the output here

My guess is : either the "bmp" file format is not supported or the rendering driver is not supported. try to use :

> SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, 0);